# I can't boot, what can I do

Tags: boot, uefi

I recently install 23.10, everything was ok.
Today my laptop wont boot, I can acces Grub and UEFI settings, but can't boot in recovery mode. After some research it seems to be a ramdisk corrupted. But there is no error message on the screen.

I have the usb key on which I install Ubuntu. I can select it woth boot manager but I can't boot in "Try or install Ubuntu", it is loading forever just like before.

What can I do ? I have few files unsaved on my laptop but after all I just want to make it works.

I dont know if this is a cause but I tried to do an UEFI update which failed with an error like "can't write into ..."

Thank you

edit: when bootibg with usb key, I am stuck after "EFI stub: Measured initrd data into PCR 9"

I found something interesting here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671087/ubuntu-21-04-hangs-at-loading-initial-ramdisk-after-kernel-update-with-luks

But the solution needs to have acces to a live usb key...

I have access to mmx64.efi but I dont even know what it's supposed to do

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO used to make your usb install media? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link. Have you ever run a memory check?

Comment: All memory tests dont run too. I dont have access to another computer now, I will check sum of usb later. But why would my usb key be corrupted if I used it to install ubuntu 2 days ago ?

Comment: Not necessarily the USB is at fault  -- hashcheck is the first check. Does it boot on another computer?  Your computer memory may be flaky, the disk may be flaky (all hardware problems to be eliminated).

Comment: Ok I installed again Ubuntu on the key, and I have got the same probleme. I am kind of desesperate right now. I am doing checksum thing
" may be flaky, the disk may be flaky" How can I check that ?

Comment: Did Windows turn on bitlocker or set Fast Start up on. Neither should really interfere with separate boot of USB, though. If Windows updated UEFI, that would reset UEFI to defaults which may have turned on Secure Boot and some have settings to restrict USB boot for security reasons. Check UEFI settings & Windows settings.